# Deleting indexed nodes in Neo4j

Tags: scala, indexing, neo4j

In Neo4j, if I delete an indexed node do I have to remove that node from the index first or will the index be updated automatically?

Here is a small (untested) example:

```
val index = graphDb.index()
val someIdx = index.forNodes("someIdx")
val someNode = graphDb.createNode()
someIdx.add(someNode, "key", "value")
```

And then:

```
//remove from someIdx???
someNode.delete()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you delete a node, you have to remove the index first. If you want to remove all mentions of a node from the index, see below:

```
    IndexManager indexManager = db.index();
    Index<Node> index = indexManager.forNodes("indexName");
    index.remove(node);
```

Comment: What happens when you try to get deleted node via an index query?

Comment: You get an exception, I can't quote the exact one, but it's something about you trying to access a node that no longer exists.

Comment: fyi, node autoindexing feature of neo4j should handle the deleted nodes indexes itself.

Comment: Yes, however it can cause performance degradations if that is a factor.

Comment: It's not exactly right about the exception. When you try to access a deleted node via an index query, there is a fault-tolerant mechanism that will de-index the deleted node. BUT: there is an issue (related to id-recycling, a neo4j internal mechanism) that can lead to index corruption. So removing indexed nodes by hand from indexes is greatly recommanded

Comment: @Cporte, you are correct. At times I have gotten an Exception because of this, but I'm unable to replicate it again.

Comment: I wish I had known this behaviour. It has has caused us some trouble. I think the neo4j docs on indexing should have made this much clearer, because strange, important side-effects can result.