# When deleting a relationship, does an index that points to that relationship get removed before reclamation of the relationship id?

Tags: neo4j

When deleting a relationship, does an index that points to that relationship get removed before reclamation of the relationship id? I believe I'm seeing a weird issue that I'm not able to reproduce with a high degree of certainty.

I have a `Relationship` that I'm putting in an index and referencing with a UUID. When I delete that a bunch of relationships in `Neo4j`, and then add a bunch, I think some of the relationship ID's are being reused(I know this is standard and I'm okay with this). My deleting of the relationships is just a delete, I'm not removing from the index that held them.

When I go to the index and do a search by the UUID, I get a bunch of bad results, IE unexpected items which my code never put in there.

I know good practice is to remove the entity from the index, but has anyone seen this problem before? Is this expected behavior?

Comment: What version of neo4j are you using? We were seeing similar behavior (randomly/inconsistently) in 1.8.2, the latest stable version.

Comment: I'm using 1.8.2 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using auto-indexes? (If not, this is how indexes work until 2.0.)

When you're not using auto-indexes, you have to explicitly add and remove things from indexes. Indexes are just pointers to node ids or rel ids.

Comment: No auto-index, but you're saying that when a node/relationship is deleted from the Graph Database, it isn't removed from the index?

Comment: Yeah. That's why I like auto-indexes (and the 2.0-style indexes).

Comment: Isn't this the same as the question you answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13587025/deleting-indexed-nodes-in-neo4j/13587360#13587360

Comment: Yes, however I'm asking here to see if anyone has encountered the reclamation of entities in an index.

Answer (score 1):

There was a problem where even auto-indexes didn't remove entities from the index until later. 1.8.1 and 1.8.2 has this fix, also the 1.9 series and forward.